# Convert a string into a models attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, `Avatar`, which has a few attributes, including `original_url`, `large_url`, and `thumb_url`. I am using [transloadit](http://transloadit.com) for file uploads, which is why I am storing these images like this.

I also have a method that takes in a few arguments, one of which is a string. Instead of creating multiple methods for each different avatar size, I'd rather create one with an argument of the which attribute to use (ie: `original_url`, `large_url`, etc).

```
def avatar_for(user, img_size, img_url)
   url = user.avatar ? user.avatar.img_url : (Identicon.data_url_for user.username, img_size, [238, 238, 238])
  image_tag(......)
end
```

The above `img_url`, is where I would pass in the specific attribute I wanted to use like this:

```
= avatar_for(current_user, 250, 'original_url')
```

However, that returns the error

```
undefined method `img_url' for #<Avatar:0x007fdc98217948>
```

How can I take this string and convert it to act as a attribute on an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert from a string to object attribute name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903763/how-to-convert-from-a-string-to-object-attribute-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the power of Ruby messaging system

Every object in ruby can receive *message* with the `send` method. Example when you do `'hello'.upcase` the output is 'HELLO'. With the `send` method you write `'hello'.send(:upcase)` for the same output. Note that I used a symbol that represent the name of the method to call.

Whats's the advantage? In my example `:upcase` can come from a variable (and that's what you want to do) but also `send` allow to call private methods on other objects.

In your case, the correct code to use is the following:

```
def avatar_for(user, img_size, img_url)
   url = user.avatar ? user.avatar.send(img_url) : (Identicon.data_url_for user.username, img_size, [238, 238, 238])
  image_tag(......)
end
```

Then you will call your method like this:

```
= avatar_for(current_user, 250, :original_url) # Using symbol instead of string
```

---

**Alternate answer**

In Rails all model (i.e. objects that derivate from `ActiveRecord::Base`) store the attribute in an array-like storage. Example if you have a `User` model with `name` attribute, you can access it with `user[:name]`

So in your case if you need an alternative to the `send` method, **given that `user.avatar` is an active record model** you can write the following:

```
def avatar_for(user, img_size, img_url)
   url = user.avatar ? user.avatar[img_url] : (Identicon.data_url_for user.username, img_size, [238, 238, 238])
  image_tag(......)
end
```

Comment: That is it. You know I tried the `send` method, as after my research on S.O. it seemed like the `send` method was the trick, I just implemented it incorrectly. Thanks @Benjamin. Will accept the answer when it allows.