# Ruby - loop to check if at least one pair of values are populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in my rails form there are several rows of 2 textfields.  For the form to save ok, at least one of the *pair* of textfields needs to be filled out.

So

```
nil   nil
10    20
nil   nil
nil   nil
```

is valid.

This:

```
nil   nil
nil   nil
nil   nil
nil   nil
```

is invalid

This:

```
nil   10
nil   nil
nil   nil
nil   nil
```

is invalid

Here is the method I am using to check all the fields (note that single_field and aggregate_field are strings and are the field names):

```
def no_values_present?(single_field, aggregate_field)
    self.lo_item.lo_line_items.each do |item|
    return false if "!item.#{single_field}".nil? && "!item.#{aggregate_field}".nil?
    end
    true
  end
```

But I guess this doesn't work as it will return true or false several times and will determine that a row is invalid even though a previous row may have been valid.

I need an overall true or false.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leveraging `any?` or `none?` from the `Enumerable` module.

Your code could be rewritten as

```
def no_values_present?(single_field, aggregate_field)
    self.lo_item.lo_line_items.none? { |item|
        !(item.send(single_field).nil?) && !(item.send(aggregate_field).nil?)
    }
end
```

although I think that it would be clearer to have the condition be positive and to return `true` when there is a match found. I would write

```
def any_pairs_present?(single_field, aggregate_field)
    self.lo_item.lo_line_items.any? { |item|
        !(item.send(single_field).nil?) && !(item.send(aggregate_field).nil?)
    }
end
```

---

Note that `"!item.#{single_field}"` will never be `nil` because it will always be a string! If you want to access instance fields dynamically then one way to do that is with `send`, but for other options you could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903763/how-to-convert-from-a-string-to-object-attribute-name) which suggests the alternatives of `instance_eval` and `instance_variable_get`.

Comment: Thanks for this makes sense week try in my am.

Answer (score 0):

The function looks ok, but there seems to be syntax errors, I'd also make a few amendments:

```
def form_valid?(single_field, aggregate_field)
    self.lo_item.lo_line_items.each do |item|
      return true if !item.send(single_field).nil? && !item.send(aggregate_field)
    end
    false
  end
```

Comment: Will try tomorrow,  I might need to post the calling code which calls the method. Will the loop return a true or false for each row? Or just return a final boolean?